# Restrict the type of a generic method on a class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I am currently working on a save system that will allow me to save data in Unity. I have a problem when it comes to the generic part. When the program wants to load a new element of type T, he will check if it exists then load it. If the element doesn't exist, a new element will be created using a constructor in the class T.

A problem happens when I tried to name the new element. I created a new class named Savable which will be parent for every data I will need to save, but I don't know how to restrict the type of the generic method so that T is considered as an element of type Savable, but the return object is of type T.

I currently tried to use the class T and to use a constructor with parameter, but it doesn't work.

Here is my current code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public static class SaveManager
{
    public static void SaveFromJson<T>(T data, string name, string path)
    {

        path = Application.persistentDataPath + path;

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        path = path + name + ".txt";

        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data, true);

        File.WriteAllText(path, json);
    }

    public static T LoadFromJson<T>(string name, string path) where T : new()
    {
        path = Application.persistentDataPath + path + name + ".txt";

        Savable data = new T();

        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(path);

            data = JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(json);
        }
        else
        {
            data.Name = name;
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Savable
{
    public string Name;
}
```

PS : Sorry for my English, it is my second language.

The solution was found. I just needed to add the constraint Savable before the constraint new().

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public static class SaveManager
{
    public static void SaveFromJson<T>(T data, string name, string path)
    {

        path = Application.persistentDataPath + path;

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        path = path + name + ".txt";

        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data, true);

        File.WriteAllText(path, json);
    }

    public static T LoadFromJson<T>(string name, string path) where T : Savable, new()
    {
        path = Application.persistentDataPath + path + name + ".txt";

        T data = new T();

        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(path);

            data = JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(json);
        }
        else
        {
            data.Name = name;
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're already using one generic type constraint on your `LoadFromJson` method. You just need to use a different constraint. Do some reading on generic type constraints and you'll find your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your clue and found the solution. I lacked some knowledge about the constraint in the generic.

Comment: Glad you found the solution. You should not leave a resolved question unanswered. If you have found the answer yourself, you should post an answer yourself and accept it. I'm not sure whether that's possible or whether some delay is required between answering and accepting for a new user but, if you don't want to or can't post an answer then you ought to delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found. I just needed to add the constraint Savable before the constraint new().

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public static class SaveManager
{
    public static void SaveFromJson<T>(T data, string name, string path)
    {

        path = Application.persistentDataPath + path;

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        path = path + name + ".txt";

        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data, true);

        File.WriteAllText(path, json);
    }

    public static T LoadFromJson<T>(string name, string path) where T : Savable, new()
    {
        path = Application.persistentDataPath + path + name + ".txt";

        T data = new T();

        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(path);

            data = JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(json);
        }
        else
        {
            data.Name = name;
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```